# Remove adjacent duplicate lines while keeping the order

Tags: awk, sed, sort, uniq

I have a file with one column with names that repeat a number of times each. I want to condense each repeat into one, while keeping any other repeats of the same name that are not adjacent to other repeats of the same name.

E.g. I want to turn the left side to the right side:

```
Golgb1    Golgb1    
Golgb1    Akna
Golgb1    Spata20
Golgb1    Golgb1
Golgb1    Akna
Akna
Akna
Akna
Spata20
Spata20
Spata20
Golgb1
Golgb1
Golgb1
Akna
Akna
Akna
```

This is what I've been using: `perl -ne 'print if ++$k{$_}==1' file.txt > file2.txt`
However, this method only keeps one representative from the left (i.e. Golb1 and Akna are not repeated).

Is there a way to keep unique names for each block, while keeping names that repeat in multiple, non-adjacent blocks?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`uniq` will do this for you:

```
$ uniq inputfile
Golgb1
Akna
Spata20
Golgb1
Akna
```

Comment: wow that was embarrassingly easy! thanks!

Comment: @Age87 Unix is great! This only works because you expect duplicates to be adjacent, already (or, don't wish to remove non-adjacent ones). Normally, the recommendation is to use `sort | uniq`

Comment: Or more succinctly, `sort -u` (:

Answer (score 10):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '$1 != name{ print }{ name = $1 }' file.txt
```

The output:

```
Golgb1
Akna
Spata20
Golgb1
Akna
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this - save the previous line and compare against current line

```
$ perl -ne 'print if $p ne $_; $p=$_' ip.txt
Golgb1
Akna
Spata20
Golgb1
Akna
```

You've tagged `uniq` as well - did you try it?

```
$ uniq ip.txt
Golgb1
Akna
Spata20
Golgb1
Akna
```

Answer (score 1):

With **sed** it can be done as follows:

```
sed -e '$!N;/^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P;D' input_file
```

Here we have in the pattern space at any time 2 lines. When the comparison between them fails we print the first one and chop it from the front and
go back and append the next line into the pattern space. Rinse...repeat

Utilizing **Perl** in the slurp mode we treat the whole file as one long
string on which the regex is applied which does the comparison for you.

```
perl -0777pe 's//$1/ while /^(.*\n)\1+/gm' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Question about Rakesh Sharma's sed solution.

What if you have a input file such as:

```
-126.1 48.206
-126.106 48.21
-126.11 48.212
-126.114 48.214
-126.116 48.216
-126.118 48.216
-126.128 48.222
-126.136 48.226
```

And you want an output file to be:

```
-126.1 48.206
-126.106 48.21
-126.11 48.212
-126.114 48.214
-126.116 48.216
-126.128 48.222
-126.136 48.226
```

Note the missing:

```
-126.118 48.216
```

I know the command I want is similar to your solution:

```
sed -e '$!N;/^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P;D' input_file
```

Cannot alter it in the right way to print both columns and only be sorted in this special way with column 2 values. Any tips?

Comment: `sed -e '$!N' -e '/.*\.\([0-9]*\)\n.*\.\1$/!{P;D;}' -e 's/\n.*//;s/^/\n/;D'`  will delete the subsequent repeating elements. Note: This requires `GNU sed`. For `POSIX` behavior, it needs slight alteration.